# Index Match Excel Multiple Tabs

Tags: excel, excel-match, vba

I am using an index match formula to find data in my workbook. The issue i have is that i need this formula to run through a series of tabs ie: `'5-13-2:5-21-3'!` this is my current formula:

```
=INDEX('C. 5-13-2'!C8:C8,MATCH("Fair - DPS Actionable",'C. 5-13-2'!F8:F8,0)
```

for each time it finds "Fair - DPS Actionable" the value of the corresponding C cell will be outputted. Any help would be great

Comment: you need one formula to look through multiple tabs at once? If so, is this because the match may exist one tab only and not others?

Comment: correct! i need the formula to check a tab range, appx 30 tabs

Comment: since it's 30 tabs, the most effecient way to do is to write one formula for each tab. You can place the sheet names as a header and use the `INDIRECT` formula to reference each sheet name. Then write a formula to grab the value from whatever tab comes. Its possible to do in one formula, but not recommended due to extreme clunkiness.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense... I am not sure how to utilize the INDIRECT formula or achieve this, can you post an answer with a suggested formula ?

Comment: [Indirect Formula](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) link will help :)

Comment: okay, i will check it out, thanks!